# Can't pass variable in KnockoutJS, when coming from a searchable list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am using Knockout to make a searchable list, using an array. Once a user searches and clicks on an option I am trying to get it to run a function. I am very new to knockout and thought that I could use 'click:' to get it work, but am unsure how to get the specific option the user selected. This is what I have so far, any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <form class= "search" action="#">
    <input class = "searchBar" placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="on">
  </form>
  <div class="content">
    <a class = "searchable" href="#" >
     <ul class= "locList" data-bind = "template: {name:'location', foreach:locations}, click: function(index) { newLocation(places.indexOf({name:'location'})[0], index)}">
     </ul>
    </a>
 </div>
```

```
<script type="text/html" id="location">
  <li class= "bullet">
    <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong><hr>
  </li>
</script>
```

JS

```
  var places = [
    ['Fort Lewis', 47.1261838830712, -122.50854491937491, 5],
    ['NAS Whidbey Island', 48.34709388383968, -122.66647338617179, 4],
    ['Bangor Base', 47.72035804907695, -122.70973205316398, 3],
    ['Keyport Base', 47.697255902139425, -122.62184142816398, 2],
    ['Naval Base Kitsap', 47.56028140643856, -122.64587402093741, 1]
  ];


  var map;
  var infowindow;

  function initMap() {
    var latlng = {lat: 47.6410663, lng: -122.6881319};
    var mapOptions = {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 8
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
        addMarkers(places[i]);
    }
  }

  function addMarkers(newPlace) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:{lat: newPlace[1], lng: newPlace[2]},
        map: map
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
       infowindow.setContent(newPlace[0]);
       infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }

  var locations = [
    {
    name: "Fort Lewis",
    index: 0},
  {
    name: "NAS Whidbey Island",
    index: 3},
  {
    name: "Bangor Base",
    index: 1},
  {
    name: "Keyport Base",
    index: 2},
  {
    name: "Naval Base Kitsap",
    index: 4}
  ];
  /* Sortable Lists */
  $(function() {

  var viewModel = {
    query: ko.observable(''),

    newLocation: function (index)
    {
      console.log(index);
      currentMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position:{lat: places[1][1], lng: places[1][2]},
          map: map
      });
      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(places[1][1], places[1][2]));
      currentMarker.addListener('center_changed', function() {
         infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
    }
  };

viewModel.locations = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(locations, function(location) {
        return location.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
    });
}, viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Comment: What does the template for your `<li>`'s look like? it looks like you've attached the click function to the entire list and not each individual item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding click function to , you should bind it to each li. Because li is under foreach binding, you should use $root or $parent to call your function - ex $parent.newLocation ( in this case both parent and root should work)

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <form class= "search" action="#">
    <input class = "searchBar" placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="on">
  </form>
  <div class="content">
    <a class = "searchable" href="#" >
     <ul class= "locList" data-bind = "foreach:locations">
     <li class= "bullet">
    <strong data-bind="text: name, click: $root.newLocation"></strong><hr>
  </li>
     </ul>
    </a>
 </div>
```

or if you still want template binding

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <form class= "search" action="#">
    <input class = "searchBar" placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="on">
  </form>
  <div class="content">
    <a class = "searchable" href="#" >
     <ul class= "locList" data-bind = "template: {name:'location', foreach:locations}">
     </ul>
    </a>
 </div>

 <script type="text/html" id="location">
  <li class= "bullet">
    <strong data-bind="text: name, , click: $parent.newLocation"></strong><hr>
  </li>
</script>
```